# How do I setup environment variables for multiple environments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, next.js

I have a Next.js application and I have currently got this next.config.js setup to access my .env file when working locally, which works fine:

```
// Initialize doteenv library
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
    config.node = {
      fs: "empty"
    };
    /**
     * Returns environment variables as an object
     */
    const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    /** Allows you to create global constants which can be configured
     * at compile time, which in our case is our environment variables
     */
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));
    return config;
  }
};
```

However when the app is built on the live (platform.sh) environment I need to access platform.sh variables instead of my .env variables. Platform.sh provide this code snippet as an example:

```
function read_base64_json(varName) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(new Buffer(process.env[varName], 'base64').toString());
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`no ${varName} environment variable`);
  }
};

// A simple variable.
let projectId = process.env.PLATFORM_PROJECT;

// A JSON-encoded value.
let variables = read_base64_json('PLATFORM_VARIABLES');
```

However I am unsure where to use this and how to it working so that locally it uses my .env file and on the live environment to use the platform.sh variables. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack.config you can reconfigure plugin section like this

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      VARIABLE_NAME:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? VARIABLE_PRODUCTION_VALUE
          : VARIABLE_LOCAL_VALUE
    })
  ]
```

You can use VARIABLE_NAME anywhere in your app and it will change depending on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

`dotenv` overrides your environment variables with the contents of the file. You probably want to `rm .env` in your build hook.